# How to use jquery Select2 in jtable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-jtable

I just using jQuery jtable in mvc application, and use cascading dropdown, I want to use select2 in a dropdown, How can I use It?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not working with jTable but i think can use jtalbe callback function on load.Try this code

```
$('.your-table').jtable('load', undefined, function(){
  $('.your-table').find('select').select2();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd put the select2 change in the recordsLoaded callback rather than the load method callback. Placing it there,  the code will be called on load, reload, addRecord and updateRecord.